# How to get quantity and weight per category via subquery in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables

1. items
2. ItemCategories
3. ItemsToPackingLists

I would like to know how to extend the following query to have:

1. the Quantity of Items per ItemCategory too (SumItemsOfCategory)
2. the Weight of Items per ItemCategory (SumWeightOfItemsOfCategory).

The subquery to calculate ItemsOfPacklist does work already. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT      items.ID,
            items.NameOfItem,
            items.WeightInGrams,

            ICategories.NameOfCategory,

            IToPLs.Quantity,
            (items.WeightInGrams * IToPLs.Quantity) AS TotalWeightInGrams,          

            (SELECT SUM(IToPLs2.Quantity)
            FROM    ItemsToPackingLists AS IToPLs2
            WHERE   PackingListID = 1
            ) AS ItemsOfPackingList

FROM trekking_Items AS items

LEFT JOIN ItemCategories AS ICategories ON
items.ItemCategoryID = ICategories.ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemsToPackingLists AS IToPLs ON
items.ID = IToPLs.ItemID

WHERE PackingListID = 1

ORDER BY ICategories.SortID ASC
```

Comment: That subquery seems like a horribly inefficient way to do this. You are hitting the same base table in your main query already. And even worse is you probably should have that subquery be a correlated subquery. As it stands it will get the same value every single time. Some basic aggregation is really all you need here. Check out this article for a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see these two pieces of data per detail row? If so, I'd recommend using window functions. MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

You could add something along the lines of:

```
SELECT...
COUNT(items.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY items.ItemCategoryID) AS SumItemsOfCategory,
SUM(items.WeightInGrams * IToPLs.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY items.ItemCategoryID) AS SumWeightOfItemsOfCategory
FROM...
```

Edit: In response to OP's comment. That was an oversight on my part. I've modified the example to take into account the number of items for the weight per category computation.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal of using window functions. Definetely useful. But it does not give the correct results, because the multiplication by the quantity of each item is missing. I am struggling to figure out where to put it.